# How to access element of unknown struct by pos?

Tags: c

In the main program, I have many different structures and associated types, and I call an external function that I keep in a separated dll:

```
typedef struct{int a; int b; int c; int d;} t1;
typedef struct{int x; int y; double z; double w;} t2;
// ...
int ret;
char* s="blah";
t1* parms1;
t2* parms2;
ret=MyFunc(s, t1);
//...
ret=MyFunc(s, t2);
```

In the dll, the above types are neither defined nor known, and I have the following function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int MyFunc(char* pstmt, void* pRS){
//--
}
```

My question is, is there a way to access (i.e. read/set) the passed struct elements inside the dll? Like, position-based access or something like that? For instance, I would like to be able to write something like:

```
pRS->*<either a or x>*=*<something>*
```

Comment: What does "position-based" mean? On what condition does the `<either a or x>` depend? And why can't the DLL know the `struct`?

Comment: `MyFunc` cannot know what `pRS` points to, you need to pass that information to the `MyFunc` function and cast `pRS` to the corresponding type (t1 or t2).

Comment: "position-based" is something I made up for  lack of a better description. pstmt should be a sql statement that MyFunc executes, and whose returned column number and types match the elements of each structures. My intent is to keep the dll as generic as possible, hence I don't want it to depend on the definition of every struct

Comment: Moving the `struct` definition to a seperate header file is a clean option and mirrors the very purpose header files were invented for. Genericity (is that the right noun for "generic"?) is not accomplished by such hacks you're asking for, i.e., calculate the offset of every member and pass it to the DLL.

Comment: Structs are meant to be known by the code that uses it. It sounds like using struct is wrong solution to this problem. DLL could return byte array of data, and additional meta data to describe the data format.

Comment: C is not well suited for what you are trying to do. A language that supports reflection,  such as c#, would be able to do what you want.

Comment: I like the suggestion about using a separate header file. I was aware I was going down some dirty road here, I was just hoping to find a "shortcut"... Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

you have to `cast` the (void*) to any wanted struct as in your case:

```
((t1*)pRS)->a=0;
```

or

```
((t2*)pRS)->x=0;
```

Comment: Problem is, the DLL doesn't know the type.

Comment: I was hoping there was some other way, perhaps considering the fact that, to my understanding, each element of any struct is held in contiguous areas of memory... Anyway, thanks for all the replies

Comment: yes indeed, each element of any struct is held in contiguous areas of memory. however struct unlike arrays, can hold elements of different sizes (char, short,int ...). how would you want to access these elements?

Comment: if elements are in the same type as in t1 you cant treat it as an array of 4 int, than you can access members as so : `((int*)pRS)[index]` where index is in range [0 ... 3]

Comment: @milevyo Sure? What if the `struct` doesn't have the alignment requirements of an `int`?

Comment: @cad, but all members of `t1` are of type int.

Comment: @milevyo Anyway, I don't think the standard guarantees the `struct` to be aligned on `int` boundaries. It probably works but is still undefined.

Comment: @cad, if any alignement happend that is in diferent size of int , then it will be by padding the struct (adding extra bits to the sturct), so it is always safe.

Comment: I'm still not entirely convinced that the standard agrees with that but nevertheless, I don't think relying on the layout of the `struct` doesn't help maintenance. (An `#include` would avoid all this hassle anyway.)

Comment: @cad, well sure, i agree with you in that point. there is other option, is to cast to an inline defined struct as  `((struct {int a,b,c,d;}*) ptr)->a`

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that syntax! Is that standard or extension?  Anyway, still bad for maintenance since a change in the `struct` requires a second change in the `struct` you're performing the cast with.